# Transform trellis object in hexbin object in R

Tags: r

It is possible to transform `trellis` (specifically `hexbinplot`) object in `hexVP` (`hexViewport`) object in R?
If yes, how to do this?

I need this because I created a graphic using `hexbinplot` the way down, which creates a `trellis` class object.

```
df <- data.frame(x, y)  #x and y are two vectors of the same size.
graphic <- hexbinplot(y ~ x, df)  #graphic is a 'trellis' class object.
```

And I want to use the code below to insert points in the graphic created by `hexbinplot`.

```
pushHexport(grafico$plot.vp)
grid.points(a, b)  #a and b are two vectors of the same size.
upViewport()
```

But this code only works in `hexVP` (`hexViewport`) class, and this is why I need to turn a `trellis` object into a `hexVP` (`hexViewport`) object.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?  _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EricFail , I guess I make it better :)